# Как достать конкретный объект из бд. python

Tags: python, sql

Подскажите, как мне достать не последний пост(.last), а именно тот пост, который я создал в тесте?

```
    def test_create_post(self): 

    """Создание поста""" 

    post_count = Post.objects.count() 

    form_data = {"text": "Тестовый текст", "group": self.group.id} 

    response = self.author.post(POST_CREATE_URL, data=form_data) 

    self.assertRedirects(response, PROFILE_URL) 

    self.assertEqual(post_count, 1) 

    self.assertEqual( 

        Post.objects.count(), post_count + 1, "Пост не создан" 

    ) 

    self.assertTrue( 

        Post.objects.filter( 

            text=form_data["text"], 

            group=form_data["group"], 
            author=self.user,
        ).exists(), 

        "Поля не совпадают", 

    ) 

    last_post = Post.objects.last() 

    self.assertEqual(last_post.text, form_data["text"]) 

    self.assertEqual(last_post.group.id, form_data["group"]) 

    self.assertEqual(last_post.author, self.user)
```

Comment: Чтобы достать что-то определённое, необходимо располагать чем-то, что однозначно идентифицирует это самое что-то. Так что, отправив пост, надо обратно получить, например, уникальный идентификатор созданной записи...

Comment: вам нужно указать больше вводных данных. какой фреймворк? какая орм? очень похоже, что Андрей Квичанский имеет отношение ко всему этому :)

Comment: @Dmitry django, sqlite. да, так и есть. Предполагаю, что мне нужен id поста, подскажите, как достать

Comment: @Skullptor987, в джанго есть замечательный метод [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), который вам вернет сам пост и булевое значение в зависимости от того, создан ли был пост, либо получен из базы уже имеющийся. Реализовать можно так: `post, status = Post.objects.get_or_create(data= ... )`